# Post request status 200 but no data in database

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I want to make a post request to the database to push a table reservation. I get a status 200 with the request I am doing.

Here is my `postReservation` method in `reservation.controller.ts`:

```
postReservation(reservation): void {
   console.log('postReservation', reservation, 'restaurantId', reservation.RestaurantID);

  this.reservationService.postReservation(
    new RequestObject({
      data: reservation,
      onSuccess: (result: Array<Reservation>) => {
        this.data.results = result;
        console.log('postReservation succes', result);

      // TODO show succes alert
      }
    })
  );
}
```

And here is the reservation.service.ts which will be extended by the `Abstractservice`

```
postReservation(requestObject = new RequestObject) {
      this.httpPost(this.apiUrl + 'tableReservation', requestObject,
            (data) => {
                console.log('succes', data.data, requestObject.data);

                // Combine succes data with reservation data - To merge reservationCode into current obj
                const reservation = { ...requestObject.data, ...data.data };
                requestObject.onSuccess(new Reservation(reservation));
            }, (err) => {
                requestObject.onFail(err);
            });
    }
```

And the `this.httpPost` above will call the httpPost method in my `abstract.service.ts`

```
httpPost(url, requestObject = new RequestObject, onSuccess = (resp) => {}, onFail = (err) => {}) {
    letbody = requestObject.options.bodyType === 'json' ? requestObject.getStringifiedBody() : requestObject.data;
    let headers = requestObject.headers ? requestObject.headers : null;

    return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers, params: requestObject.getQueryParams()})
        .pipe(
            map(response => response),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        ).subscribe(
            (resp) => {
                if (requestObject.loader) this.globalService.onHideLoader.emit(requestObject.loaderId);
                console.log('httpPost SUCCES', resp);
                onSuccess(resp);
                requestObject.onDone(resp);
            },
            (err) => {
                if (requestObject.loader) this.globalService.onHideLoader.emit(requestObject.loaderId);

                // Execute own errorHandling when response has no errorHandling
                // if (!requestObject.hasErrorHandling) this.onError(err);
                requestObject.onDone(err);
                onFail(err);
            }
        );
}
```

So I get status 200 but when I make an call to get all reservations, the reservation does not popup. But when I make the exact same call from postman, with the same body the data pops up.

Comment: did you check in the browser, if data being sent properly to the API call ?

Comment: It looks correct in the body from request. How else csn I check?

Comment: If you can see it in the body that means it is correct, now please check it's the response as well on the same API request on the browser.

Comment: @VarunSukheja the response is indeed different.

Comment: So what else could you recommend me?

Comment: I would say to check the response in browser with response in map mentioned in pipe.